# How to give delay alert in JavaScript for broad wildcard searches

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have an requirement to give note warning of delayed processing times for broad wildcard searches

when the user enter %(wildcard) in text field and when click on submit button need to give Warning! message "**There should be delay processing time for broad wild card searches"**

Currently my java script is like below

```
 if(Description!=""){
    var artDesc = artDescription;
    var wild = "%";
    if(artDesc.indexOf(wild) != -1 && artDesc.indexOf(wild) < 2){
        alert("Enter atleast two characters before wildcard");
        return false;
    }
```

In addition to above how to add the above alert. Please help on this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `else` part of it. In the `if` condition you're making sure there's no search term at all, then in the else, you can be sure that there is one for sure.

```
if(artDesc.indexOf(wild) != -1 && artDesc.indexOf(wild) < 2){
    alert("Enter atleast two characters before wildcard"); // nothing entered
    return false;
} else {
   alert ("This will take some time to process"); // something entered
}
```